# Register files for cache in PWA with React

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Does anyone know how he could cache the files for a PWA with React?

I'm working with a custom service-worker and I'm trying to register the necessary files to run the application in offline mode, but no matter how hard I try, I can never do it since the server can not find them. I have tried in this way:

```
const cacheUrls = [
        '/',
    ];

self.addEventListener('install', event => {

    const promesaDeInstalacion = caches.open('cache-3') 
        .then( cache => { 
          return cache.addAll(
            cacheUrls
            );
    });

    event.waitUntil(promesaDeInstalacion);
});
```

Where cacheUrls is the array where I will indicate which files will be saved in cache.

For this I have also tried it in this way:

```
const cacheUrls = [
    '/',
    'build/static/css/**.css',
    'build/static/js/**.js',
    'build/media/**.jpg'
];
```

Also from this:

```
const cacheUrls = [
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    '/static/css/',
    '/static/js/',
    '/static/media/',
];
```

But the result is always the same. So I do not know how to cache files to have my PWA offline.

Comment: can you add the absolute paths where your files are in which are used on your website? is it build or static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved adding files to cache from this way:

```
const cacheUrls = [
"static/css/main.c16ed571.chunk.css",
"static/js/1.2dd891c4.chunk.js",
"static/js/main.182aaaa5.chunk.js",
"static/js/runtime~main.229c360f.js"
]
```

Comment: What if you create a new build? New build create new build files with different checksum. So you can't hard code file names.

Comment: @VaibhavKumar Did you find an alternative solution to hardcoding checksums in?

Answer (score -1):

try like:

```
const cacheUrls = [
    '/',
    '/build/static/css/*.css',
    '/build/static/css/**/*.css',
    '/build/static/js/*.js',
    '/build/static/js/**/*.js',
    '/build/media/**/*.jpg',
    '/build/media/*.jpg'
];
```

where double asterix `**` is for subfolders and a single asterix `*` for any file ending with `.fileextension`.

don't know how many files you want to store. In my upper example you will match all CSS files in the CSS direcotry and all it's subdirectories.

Comment: thank you friend but it does not work, it just caches the path **/build/static/css/**/*.css** as a string but when checking the file it's just the index.html

Comment: updated my post. think you need to prepend a `/` before `build`

Comment: I appreciate your help but it seems there is no solution. At the moment I managed to have the files cached in this way: 'static / css / main.54770f01.chunk.css',
'static / js / 1.2dd891c4.chunk.js',
'static / js / main.e4f2a192.chunk.js',
'static / js / runtime ~ main.229c360f.js',

Comment: But if for some reason I add an image it is never cached. Not to mention I've been with this for several days and I do not get any good solution (I've tried with React and VUE) it will be better to do it without React. Thank you!